# Bytes prepended to text file

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, encoding

I am reading some CSV file in Python. The file was uploaded from Windows to AWS S3 and then downloaded using [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request). The file should start with

```
some text
```

but instead it starts with

```
b'u\xabZj\x9ae\x89\xc6\xad\x8a\x89\xff\xbewf\xb1\xec\\zV\xda\xb1\xee\xb8\xef\xbb\xbfsome text
```

So, when this piece of code gets executed:

```
filetemp = urllib.request.urlopen(file_url)
    content = filetemp.read(1024)
```

the `content` variable starts with

```
b'u\xabZj\x9ae\x89\xc6\xad\x8a\x89\xff\xbewf\xb1\xec\\zV\xda\xb1\xee\xb8\xef\xbb\xbf**some text
```

Can it be some kind of BOM? It doesn't look like any BOM that I am familiar with. I used [chardet](https://chardet.github.io/) to find out the file was encoded using Windows-1252 encoding, and when I decode it using that encoding, I get

```
u«Zjše‰Æ­Š‰ÿ¾wf±ì\\zVÚ±î¸ï»¿some text
```

When I open the file in Excel or Notepad, it seems fine and it starts with `some text`. So, obviously they know how to handle it, but I don't. What am I missing?

**Update**: When I download this file on Mac and read it the same way (using the same code), it is only prepended with `\xef\xbb\xbf`, which is UTF-8 BOM. So it is Windows that is adding those other bytes.

**Update 2**: Ok, it's got to be something with `urllib.request`, because when I download that file manually from AWS S3 and execute the following Python script:

```
file = open('myfile.csv', 'r')
filecontent = file.read()
file.close()
```

the `filecontent` variable does not contain those weird bytes, just BOM. It might be a similar issue to the one [usr2564301](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2564301/usr2564301) linked in his comment.

Comment: Can you put in the hex values for this header, or try with [`file`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)) to see what it is you're getting? Maybe it's compressed. Based on the paste here I can't tell what it is.

Comment: `file` doesn't give:
$ cat >wtf <<EOF
> u«Zjše‰Æ­Š‰ÿ¾wf±ì\\zVÚ±î¸ï»¿some text
> EOF
$ file wtf
wtf: UTF-8 Unicode text

Comment: `\xef\xbb\xbf` is definitely UTF-8 (and most likely the beginning of your file).

Comment: Can you reliably reproduce the download of those extra bytes, or did it only happen once? Can you reproduce it on a different Windows machine? (One possible explanation: is there a proxy of some sort in between your Windows machine and S3?)

Comment: Those are the same bytes as in a *remotely possibly* related [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34035761), using a perl URL reader. But, if they are part of the URL specifications, surely there would be more hits ...

Comment: @DanielPryden It happens every time I download it using `urllib.request`. But when I download it manually and read it, everything is fine (look at the Update 2).

Comment: @JoshLee It is.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution with the help of [usr2564301's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2564301/usr2564301) comment. String `data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,` was prepended to the HTTP request payload when uploading the file. [This answer can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34036750/3133442) can be applied to my issue.